# how to use a 32 gigabyte sd card for raspberrypi zero w?

Tags: ssh, pi-zero, headless, image, raspberry-pi-imager

I've been trying to ssh to a raspberry pi with a 32 gigs sd card with no progress. I've been using raspberry pi imager for a while with other 16 gigs sd's on other pi zero w with expected results. This is the first time that i use a 32 gigs sd card. The sd card have been formatted by me to be a fat32 file system and i deleted all the partitions it had before. I'm doing the ssh headless and I'm installing raspberry pi OS lite (32 bit).

When I'm done installing the image, I see that everything is correct and that there is data inside the card, but for some reason every time that I use arp -a in my main computer after powering on the raspberry pi, I never see a proper MAC address with it's proper IP address.

I was expecting to see the beginning of the raspberry Mac address something like this 'b8:27:eb:...' and it's corresponding IP with no luck.

Comment: You NEED a monitor to setup Raspberry Pi OS.  What does it show on screen?

Comment: @Milliways you categorically don't. If you follow the [documention](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-headless-raspberry-pi) you can have headless without needing to have graphical access. OP - I'd suggest using the link above to set this up rather than the installer you mentioned in your original post on SO

Comment: not all pi's use `b8:27:eb:` ... also, don't forget, the first boot resizes the root partition, which can take some time on an sd card

Comment: @JaromandaX early RPis use `b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx` modern ones use `d8:3a:dd:xx:xx:xx`.

Comment: @Dougie - yes, I did say NOT all use `b8:27:eb` - mine is a `DC:A6:32` so, your comment seems to be no 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the 32GB is not the issue, it looks more like a network thing.

Pi's can have different MAC ID's. As far as I know:

```
28:CD:C1:xx:xx:xx
B8:27:EB:xx:xx:xx
D8:3A:DD:xx:xx:xx
DC:A6:32:xx:xx:xx
E4:5F:01:xx:xx:xx
```

is the current list of vendor IDs assigned to the Raspberry Pi Foundation.

Alternatively, you can edit `avahi.conf` and un-comment the line

```
#allow-interfaces=<interface name>
```

and uncomment the line

```
#host-name=raspberrypi
```

(and perhaps give it a creative hostname)

Using mDNS, you should be able to reach the Pi as `raspberrypi.local`.